# How to update a variable from another scope from within a callback function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, callback, scope

I'm having trouble updating a variable that doesnt share the same scope as the callback function which itself is an argument in the jQuery getJSON invocation. Can someone tell me how I can push elements onto the chg_percent variable from within the callback function below? Thank you!

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    chg_percent = []; // array of all percent changes

    var url = 'http://finance.yahoo.com/webservice/v1/symbols/allcurrencies/quote?format=json&view=basic&callback?';

    $.getJSON(url, null, function(data) {

        for (i = 0; i < data.list.resources.length; i++) {
        chg_percent.push(data.list.resources[i].resource.fields.chg_percent);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Before answers start raining down, that snippet of code actually works and there's no scope issue with `chg_percent`. Can you clarify the scope issue again?

Comment: Look at the console when you run it. I expect the problem is actually the [same origin policy]{http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy}. As @Alexander said, there is no scope issue.

Comment: There is a scope problem as far as I can see. Even if I do this:
    chg_percent.push(3);

And then after the .getJSON invocation go alert(chg_percent) it hasnt been pushed onto it. And there is no same_origin problems here. This is jsonp and it gets the data with no issue.

Comment: I see, you can bypass CORS. I'm off here. Good luck

Comment: Before leaving, [I will leave this fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/2Y7dk/)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Add `chng_percent` as parameter along with the `function(data) { ... }`.

It should look like this:

```
$.getJSON(url, null, function(data, chng_percent) {
```